# Creation of libBox2D.a when Box2D is compiled?

Tags: c++, box2d, codeblocks

I am trying to get the most recent version of the libBox2D.a file for updating an old project that uses Box2D. I am using Code::Blocks and Windows 7 64-bit.

I have added the Box2D folder into a Code::Blocks project, and got the HelloWorld.cbp applet to build and run.  I expected a lib folder to be created and the .a file to be there, but it's not. The question is, How does libBox2D.a get generated, and where does it go?

Comment: Step by step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351640/how-to-compile-box2d-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your codeblocks project is setup correctly, the `libBox2D.a` library gets produced as the end result of building the corresponding project file. What you have to figure out is whether the project is setup to build Box2D as a shared dll or as a static library.

You can find the destination of the build output under *project options*->*Build targets*->*Output filename*. That field should tell you where to find the output. If that doesn't help, you can open a cmd.exe shell and go into Box2D's working directory and do a manual search. For example:

```
cd YOUR_Box2D_DIRECTORY_GOES_HERE
dir/s/a/w lib*.a
```

Comment: Yes thank you - I figured out to use cmake to generate the necessary project files, then I went into the destination output and found the appropriate file.